# Please explain what's wrong with the proof that every group element is its own inverse.

Tags: group-theory, fake-proofs

What is wrong with my proof here?

Proof:

Let $a, b$ be elements of a group and let $aa = b$.

Through manipulation, we see that 
$$a = ba^{-1}$$
$$b^{-1}a = a^{-1}$$
$$b^{-1}aa^{-1} = e$$
$$b^{-1} = e$$

We of course know that
$bb^{-1} = e$
And from above, we see that
$be = e$
or
$b = e$.
And since $aa = b$, we can see that $aa = e$ and that $a=a^{-1}$.

Comment: Step 2 to 3, you multiplied $a^{-1}$ on one side and $a$ on the other?

Comment: how did tou get from step 2 to 3?

Comment: 3. line is wrong

Comment: I see now, thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

In going from

$$b^{-1}a = a^{-1}$$

to

$$b^{-1}aa^{-1} = e$$

we had *already* assumed the conclusion, because we implicitly used the "fact" that $(a^{-1})^2 = e$.

Answer (score 2):

From 
$$ b^{-1}a=a^{-1}$$ multiplying by $a$ you get $$ ba^2=e, $$ not the line you got.